# How can we wait for the NOT conditions using protractor.ExpectedConditions?

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am currently working with Protractor and TypeScript, and I wish to implement a function that waits for the element text to not be something.

```
myElement: protractor.ElementFinder = $('#title');
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(
    myElement, '0'))
.then(() => return myElement.text();
```

How can I manipulate this so that I'm waiting for the element.text() to be something other than 0?

I realize that I can use the expect statement to check that the value is not 0, but I actually want to return a value from this function, and then check that the value is equal to another within a different class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might help you http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.not

Comment: Thank you @SudharsanSelvaraj - that was incredibly helpful!

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj consider posting it as an answer - don't forget to provide an example. Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe sure!! posted it as answer!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protractor supports `not` operation in ExpectedCondition. Have a look at http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.not

look at below example to solve your problem.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.not(EC.textToBePresentInElement(myElement, '0')),5000);
```